# Azure Blob Storage Returns 404 from Azure App Service

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage, azure-appservice

I have .NET Core 5 API that will call Azure Blob Storage to retrieve a file and return it back to the client in the form of base 64 string.

The code works perfectly in my local machine but when I deploy the code into Azure App Service, it always return 404 without any other error message.

This is the code that I use to download the file from Azure Blob Storage:

```
    public async Task<string> GetDocumentBase64StringAsync(
        string filePath,
        ContainerCategory containerCategory,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var cleanedFilePath = filePath.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
        var containerName = GetContainerName(containerCategory);
        var containerClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(cleanedFilePath);

        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(memoryStream, cancellationToken);
        var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        return $"data:image/png;base64,{base64String}";
    }
```

The blob client itself is using this constructor:

```
var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(azureBlobStorageSettings.ConnectionString);
```

The connection string is using the Connection String from Azure Portal > Storage Account > Access Key

Is there any specific settings that I need to enable on both Blob Storage and App Service in Azure Portal to make this work?

**UPDATE:**

The `filePath` value will look like this: `ABC\\DEF\\GHI1234\\abcdef.pdf`

If I hard code the value inside the code, it works:

```
var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("ABC\\DEF\\GHI1234\\abcdef.pdf");
```

but if it's coming from the parameter, it does not work.

Comment: What's the value of `filePath` variable?

Comment: Please try by changing `var cleanedFilePath = filePath.Replace(@"\\", @"\");` to `var cleanedFilePath = filePath.Replace(@"\\", @"/");`.

Comment: @GauravMantri still not working when it is deployed in Azure App Service

Comment: Can you confirm if the blob is present in the container at the path you’re specifying?

Comment: @GauravMantri yes the blob is present. As I mention before, the API works fine from my local machine, but it does not work once it is deployed in Azure AppService. I can get the base 64 string from that blob when I run it locally.

Comment: Your code looks ok to me. Do you get a 404 error from this method or from your API endpoint?

Comment: @GauravMantri i try it on the API endpoint, strange enough it does not have any error log at all, just straight 404.

Comment: In that case, I would say there's an issue with your API endpoint.

Comment: @GauravMantri I have updated the question with new finding. do you have any idea why it would behave like that?

Comment: Can you try by changing `var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(cleanedFilePath);` with. `var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(filePath);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the API method from `GET` to `POST` and pass in the `filepath` in the request body and it works fine now.

Previously, the API signature is:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("document/{filepath}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetDocumentBase64StringAsync(
   string filepath,
   CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
```

and now:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("document")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetDocumentBase64StringAsync(
   [FromBody] GetDocumentBase64Request request,
   CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
```

So I guess the problem is when passing the filepath as URL parameter, the `\\` is messed up because of the encoding.

If there is other method that could handle the `\\` in the URL parameter, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because locally you have full access to local storage, while running on App Service, as it's a shared environment, you need to use Temp folder. The environment variable %TEMP% will return D:\local which should be used to upload / read the files you need.

As another option, you can upload the files to a storage account and the files from it.

more info: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system

Comment: I don't think that's the reason. OP is downloading the blob in memory stream and not saving on local disk. Also, it should not have resulted in 404 error.

Comment: I don't save the file into local disk. It is a straight download to memory stream then convert it into base64 string.

Comment: you've mentioned filePath has the content: ScanDocs\\BOM\\BOM06161\\815735eaa8.pdf . What is the prefix? c drive? d?